# Upload photo with codeception

Tags: codeception

I'm doing a automated test in a drupal site with codeception. In this test I need to create a news content. But I need to upload a photo to this news and I don't find any manner to do this. To make it easy to understand, in the test it will be fill the title and description field, after that it will click in the upload field and select a photo from project files to upload.
I need a manner to do this upload with the codeception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `attachField` method - https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#attachFile

```
$I->attachFile('input[@type="file"]', 'prices.xls');
```

Field label, XPath or CSS Path expression can be used as the first parameter,
see examples at https://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#Click